# Custom overflow icon is too big (Using android.support.v7 and AppCompat)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-resources, android-styles, android-icons

My goal is to have the action bar be a red color, but since my only options from the default android library were white and black, I tried customizing it. I made some custom red icons by using a paint bucket on gimp to just fill in the white icons and re-save it under a different name. I did the same thing with the overflow icon, but for some reason, it's rendering a lot bigger than my other icons, which I don't want.

I am using `android:minSdkVersion="15"` and `targetSdkVersion 21` and the support library (specifically, `android.support.v7`).  My activity extends `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` and contains a fragment filling the whole activity. But my overflow icon is bigger than the other ones, but I want them to be the same size:

[image]

**I know it is choosing the right icon because they are both blue. It must be resizing a different way, but I don't know why?** I actually have 5 differently-colored zoom-in icons in `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-xxhdpi`, and `drawable-xxxhdpi`, just so I can see if the problem is the wrong icon being used.

When I use the default icons that come with the `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse` parent theme, then the sizes all look the same:

[image]

**Experiment using the "more vertical" icon:**

Using the `drawable-xxhdpi` size looks like this:

[image]

I tested a smaller icon (`drawable-mdpi` size) by putting it in `drawable` and forcing it to be used (even though my android uses the drawable-xxhdpi icons), but it ended up being blown up to a large size anyway:

[image]

**Here is my custom theme code that I used:**

```
<style name="NGT48Theme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/NGT48ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/NGT48ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/NGT48Theme.OverFlow</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/NGT48Theme.OverFlow</item>
    </style>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ActionBar styles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<style name="NGT48ActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/NGT48ActionBarTitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/NGT48ActionBarTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ActionBar Title Text Styles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <style name="NGT48ActionBarTitleTextStyle"
           parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
           >
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red_NGT48</item>
    </style>


    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Overflow Icon Styles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <style name="NGT48Theme.OverFlow" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_zoom_in_red_48dp</item>
    </style>
```

---

**Edit:** Here are the results of Ivan's answer. I downloaded 24dp versions of the icon, changed the color, tested it, and it worked! :)

[image]

Comment: how did you justify that icon size is incorrect ?

Comment: @CoasMckey because it's too big

Comment: you may resize the icon in all directories

Comment: @CoasMckey it didn't work

Comment: What's the resolution of your `xxhdpi` icon?

Comment: @IvanBartsov 48dp (because I downloaded 48dp icons from android's website, and just changed the color to red and re-saved it), and 144 x 144 pixels. All of my icons in the xxhdpi folder are the same pixel dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *more* [aka *action overflow*] icon is what's called a [*system icon* in Google's design spec](http://www.google.ru/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons), and according to the spec, size should be `24dp` (as opposed to usual `48dp` of a [*product icon*](http://www.google.ru/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons))

So, for `xxhdpi` your icon size should be `72px`. You can also check out the original Material icon. For `appcompat`, it's location is `../appcompat-v7/[version]/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha.png`

**PS**
Actually, if you only need to change the color of the *more* button (and text, as I see from screenshots), another option is to just use *tinting* to color the items. Appcompat supports it for all widgets in Toolbar, stock icons are uncolored and alpha-enabled, to allow tinting.

Use stock drawable of the icon (i.e. don't override) and add (I may be a bit rusty on this)

```
// Text color
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/red</item>
// Icon color
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/red</item>
```

To your actionbar theme.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I tried it and it indeed works now! I put a picture in my original post to show the results.

Comment: @RockLee no problem mate :)

Comment: @RockLee Also, check the PS section of the answer, I think there's a simpler way of accomplishing your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Image Asset within res directory, just select; Icon type:(Action Bar and Tab Icons), and Asset Type:(Image), add your image and it's done. Add your new drawable resource